# how to manually trigger an event

Tags: vb.net, forms, events

I have been away from VB for several years and am now jumping in on visual studio 2015.  Fine product so far.

I am creating a form with a data window (grid) and want to add a search filter.  I followed the help and did exactly what they said and it worked.  BUT......
It is very inefficient on the user in that you have to tab out of the criteria window (customer name is ??) to the next field which sole purpose is to allow the user to filter the datagrid data by pressing enter (Click event)

I want to trigger the code that filter the data (fillbycitytoolstripbuttonClick()) when the user leaves the text box where they entered the filtering criteria  (CityToolStripTextBox_Leave) event.

I know this is easy i just can't find the code to do this and i have tried many attempts.
Thanks in advance.     Mike

Comment: Call it whenever you want: `CityToolStripTextBox_Leave(CityToolStripTextBox, EventArgs.Empy)`

Comment: That's not really good advice. While it's possible, good practice dictates that you don;t call and event handler directly.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at this the wrong way. You don't care about raising an event. What you care about is executing some code. What you want to do is execute that code when `Click` event is raised on your button and when the `Leave` event is raised on your text box so that's exactly what you should do. Put the code that does the filtering in its own method and then simply call that method from both the handlers for both those events.